# Как нaстроить .htaccess на nginx для hhvm?

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, nginx, virtual-hosts

У меня на виртуальный хост home page сайта открывается, но ссылки не работают. Думаю, что это может быть от .htaccess rewrite. Как могу настроить .htaccess для nginx hhvm, и чтобы все ссылки работали. нажимая на ссылок дает 404 error.

Comment: Схему со смыслозначащими конфигами добавьте, плиз

Comment: в .htaccess я нечего не настроила, у меня есть настроина для apache2 a сейчас нужно для nginx hhvm. Для apache a2enmod rewrite а как для nginx ?

Comment: попробовала htaccess to nginx converter но это не сработала

Answer (score 2):

*.htaccess* — это фича исключительно веб-сервера Apache, и nginx, соотвтственно, её не поддерживает. У вас три пути:

1. Выкинуть *.htaccess* и закинуть все правила в код или конфиг nginx.

   1. Если в *.htaccess* одно правило, которое звучит как "перенаправить все запросы на единственный входной скрипт", то вам повезло.
   2. Если *.htaccess* забит под завязку, то придётся попотеть. У nginx тоже есть переписывание URL, но надо будет конвертировать весь код. Есть онлайн-трансляторы синтаксиса.
2. Использовать nginx в качестве прокси к Apache. Например, отдавать статику через nginx, а скрипты PHP перенаправлять Apache.
3. Не мучаться с nginx. Если вы не разбираетесь в конфигах nginx, а сайт разработан для Apache, то просто пользуйтесь Apache. Он не настолько плох, а HHVM работает и с ним.

P. S. Учтите, что использование *.htaccess* плохо сказывается на производительности, поэтому, если сервер полностью ваш, и не надо разделять его под отдельных клиентов, то *.htaccess* рекомендуется отключить и на Apache.

Comment: Выкинуть .htaccess и закинуть все правила в код или конфиг nginx. Не могу найти документацию на русском. можете помочь ?

Comment: @NarineGrigoryan, [документация к программе nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/)

Comment: Кажется что другая документация не сушествует. Ладно попробую читать и понять. Спасибо за помощь.