# Конвертировать htaccess для nginx

Tags: .htaccess, apache, nginx

В CMS имеется вот такое в htaccess, как это перенести в nginx.conf?

```
RewriteRule ^info/(\d+)/*$ ?info=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/*$ ?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1&$2&$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1&$2&$3&$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2&$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2&$3&$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2&$3&$4&$5 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2&$3&$4&$5&$6[QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)-(\w+)/*$ ?$1=$2&$3&4=$5 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)-(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)-(\w+)/*$ ?$1&$2=$3&$4&$5=$6 [L]
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467771/178576

Comment: Либо ищите пример конфигурации nginx для вашей cms.